# Python: upsampling dataframe from daily to hourly data using ffill()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to upsample my data from daily to hourly frequency and forward fill missing data.

I start with the following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.csv")   
df1.head(5)
```

[image: Header]

I then used the following to convert to a datetime string and set the date/time as an index:

```
df1['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DT']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df1.set_index('DT')
```

[image]

I try to resample hourly as follows:

```
df1['DT'] = df1.resample('H').ffill()
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

I thought my dtype was already date time as instructed by the pd.to_datetime code above. Nothing I try seems to be working. Can anyone please help me?

My expected output is as follows:

```
DT                  VALUE
2016-08-01 00:00:00 0.000000
2016-08-01 01:00:00 0.000000
2016-08-01 02:00:00 0.000000
```

etc.

The file itself has approximately 1000 rows. The first 50 rows or so are zero so to clarify where there's actual data:

```
DT                  VALUE
2018-12-13 00:00:00 24000.000000
2018-12-13 01:00:00 24000.000000
2018-12-13 02:00:00 24000.000000
...
2018-12-13 23:00:00 24000.000000
2018-12-14 00:00:00 26000.000000
2018-12-14 01:00:00 26000.000000
```

etc.

Comment: Mention your expected output.

Comment: @AbdurRehman Thanks for your comment, I've updated the original.

Comment: Mention `column_names` on data to make it more clear. Your actual data has year `2018` and your expected data has year `2016`.Is it right or mistyped ?

Comment: Thanks Abdur, I've updated the column names. There's about 3 years worth of data, preceded by mostly zeros. I've clarified it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try assign it back

```
df1=df1.set_index('DT')
```

Or

```
df1.set_index('DT',inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi W-B, thanks for your answer. I tried this out but unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: df1.VALUE.resample('H').ffill() does this have errors @GJB

Comment: I now get the issue AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'VALUE'

Comment: My mistake, I made a typo:
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming some initial rows of your dataset as you mentioned,

```
          DT    VALUE
0   2016-08-01  0
1   2016-08-02  0
2   2016-08-03  0
3   2016-08-04  0
4   2016-08-05  0
5   2016-08-06  0
6   2016-08-07  0
7   2016-08-08  0
8   2016-08-09  0
```

Then, make index on `DT` like this,

```
df = df.set_index('DT')
df
```

Output:

```
           VALUE
   DT   
2016-08-01  0
2016-08-02  0
2016-08-03  0
2016-08-04  0
2016-08-05  0
2016-08-06  0
2016-08-07  0
2016-08-08  0
2016-08-09  0
```

Now, resample your dataframe,

```
df = df.resample('H').ffill()
df
```

Output: showing some initial values of output,

```
                VALUE
    DT  
2016-08-01 00:00:00 0
2016-08-01 01:00:00 0
2016-08-01 02:00:00 0
2016-08-01 03:00:00 0
2016-08-01 04:00:00 0
2016-08-01 05:00:00 0
2016-08-01 06:00:00 0
2016-08-01 07:00:00 0
2016-08-01 08:00:00 0
2016-08-01 09:00:00 0
2016-08-01 10:00:00 0
```

Comment: @GJB let me know this worked for you or you have any other queries.

Comment: Hi Abdur, I got the following error: 

index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

Comment: I found the error- there was an errant NaN in the data right at the end. Many thanks Abdur.

Comment: what about the timezone, or on days with daylight saving?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the index to a `pd.DatetimeIndex` and then resample that. I also don't think you need (or want) the `strftime()` call:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.csv")
df1['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DT'])
df1.set_index('DT')
df1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1.index)
df1['DT'] = df1.resample('H').ffill()
```

NOTE: You could probably combine a bunch of this and it would still be quite clear, like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.csv")
df1.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df1['DT']))
df1['DT'] = df1.resample('H').ffill()
```